# okta - not working in Production for Edge and IE only

Tags: webforms, okta

I have an odd okta issue.

I have a old Web Forms app that I am integrating with okta.

The problem is after I login using okta, okta navigates the app to https://domain/authorization-code/callback.  This is the value in the address bar of the browser.  The app is not automating navigating to the call back page (my default.aspx page). See screen shot below.

[image]

Here is what is really confusing, this issue only happens in Production and in browsers:  Edge and IE. For Production, everything works fine using Chrome. (After I log in, I am navigated to my default.aspx page).

Additionally what is confusing is everything also works fine in Dev, QA and UAT using Chrome, Edge and IE.

This issue only occurs in Production, using Edge or IE.

I assume it is not a browser issue / setting since it works fine in the other environments.  Plus I assume it is not a server side setting since it work fine in Chrome in Production.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Plus suggestions in how to debug. I am trying to use the Network tab of the Developer Tools, but I not having much luck.

Thanks

Comment: We fixed this problem, months ago.  It was because Production is https and QA and UAT were http. I updated the urls in the General tab inside okta to https and everything started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed this problem, months ago. It was because Production is https and QA and UAT were http. I updated the urls in the General tab inside okta to https and everything started working.